# Detect spans of consecutive values with average over certain limit

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, algorithms

I have weekly data for volume of product ordered by any customer. I want to identify the **longest span of consecutive weeks** such that the average of that span is >= 33,000 (approximate; up to -2000 under would be okay too). There can be multiple distinct spans. **Spans must be at least 4 weeks long**.

A dummy dataset is given below in `r`. The expected output for this dataset is span 17-32 and span 45-48 as highlighted by the green line. Span 1-2 is not good as it's not at least 4 weeks long.

I need to do thousands of datasets and was wondering if there's a good algorithm to help with this. I feel hierarchical clustering or DBSCAN might be useful here but I couldn't get the right results.

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  week = 1:52,
  vol = c(rnorm(2, 35000, 1000),
          runif(14, 12000, 20000), 
          rnorm(7, 35000, 1000),
          runif(1, 12000, 20000),
          rnorm(8, 35000, 1000), 
          runif(12, 12000, 20000),
          rnorm(4, 35000, 100),
          runif(4, 12000, 20000)
          )
)

barplot(df$vol, names.arg = df$week)
```

[image]

Comment: Restate the problem in terms of *sums* and then solve it quickly and easily by processing the cumulative sum series.

Comment: @whuber How would a cumulative sum help detect span in the middle of the year as shown in figure. I'd need 49 different cumulative sums (since span should be at least 4 weeks long), each starting from week 1, 2,...so on. Can you elaborate of your suggestion?

Comment: You need only a single cumulative sum. Differencing it at appropriate lags will efficiently detect intervals whose sums meet any desired criterion.

Comment: @whuber If I understand this is still brute force-y. I don't know the length of spans beforehand so would need to try out all possible lags for differencing. Would you consider answering with pseudocode? That'd be of great help.

Comment: You don't need to know the lengths beforehand, because you can establish bounds on longer spans as you process shorter spans.  This is far from brute force: indeed, it's asymptotically optimal.  But this site isn't the place to be discussing basic algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about @whuber's cumulative sum approach,
but the following, using `zoo::rollsum()` is reasonably fast.

It leaves the problem that many of the spans it finds are nested within a larger span, but I'll leave that one with you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  week = 1:52,
  vol = c(rnorm(2, 35000, 1000),
          runif(14, 12000, 20000), 
          rnorm(7, 35000, 1000),
          runif(1, 12000, 20000),
          rnorm(8, 35000, 1000), 
          runif(12, 12000, 20000),
          rnorm(4, 35000, 100),
          runif(4, 12000, 20000)
  )
)

find_longest_spans = function(values, required_mean = 33000, min_span=4){
  max_span = length(values)
  # Create arrays for results.
  # NB: Is max_span**2 really the maximum possible number of runs?
  starts   = array(dim=max_span**2)
  stops = array(dim=max_span**2)
  lengths  = array(dim=max_span**2)
  averages = array(dim=max_span**2)
  ix = 1
  for(span in seq(min_span, max_span)){
    rolling_mean = zoo::rollsum(values, span, align='left') / span
    for(start in which(rolling_mean > required_mean)){
      starts[ix] = start
      stops[ix] = start + span
      lengths[ix] = span
      averages[ix] = rolling_mean[start]
      ix = ix + 1
    }
  }
  result = data.frame(start=starts, stop=stops, length=lengths, average=averages)
  return(result[1:(ix-1),])
}

spans = find_longest_spans(df$vol)

spans %>% 
  mutate(ix=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin=start, xmax=stop, y=ix, color=average)) +
  geom_linerange() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 52)) +
  labs(x='Week', y='Span ID', color='Span mean') +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: This basically looks like brute force but seems fast enough that it should be okay I guess. FYI, needs following correction - `stops[ix] = start + span - 1`. Based on whuber's comments, apparently there's a way to bound the longest span so that we don't have to evaluate all possibilities. Anyways, I'll give you the bounty if no one else answers. Thanks for the answer!